AR Culling (Depth Culling) Not Working on iOS Devices in Unity
I am having trouble with AR culling (depth culling) on iOS devices while building app in unity. The issue occurs on both an iPhone 11 and an iPhone 13. To ensure it's not specific to my project, I also built and tested the AR sample provided by Unity, but the same problem arises.
Here are the specifics:
Unity Version: 2022.3.18f1
iOS Devices Tested: iPhone 11, iPhone 13
The AR objects are not being culled correctly based on depth, which results in rendering issues. I've followed the standard procedures and settings for AR development in Unity, but the problem persists.
Has anyone else faced a similar issue? Is there a known solution or workaround for AR culling issues on iOS with Unity? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
